# how to get updated quantity when Add to cart function is called React or Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

currently quantity is 1, how do i get updated quantity when addTocart function is called,
if i enter 4 in the TextField i need  quantity  to be updated to 4 and get that object in addTocart function, currently i am getting quantity is 1

```
const allProducts=[
    { id:1, productName:'Apple',price:100,quantity:1}
    { id:2, productName:'Cherry',price:70,quantity:1}
    { id:3, productName:'Orange',price:60,quantity:1}
    { id:4, productName:'Grapes',price:69,quantity:1}
]
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, allProducts)
```

newItem is { id:4,   productName:'Grapes',  price:69,  quantity:updatedQuantity}

```
const addToCart = (newItem) => {
     //want updated quantity when this function called      
}
```

```
{ state.map(item=>(
   <div>
     <TextField defaultValue={item.quantity} />  

     <Button  onClick={()=>addTocart(item)} > Add to cart</Button>
  </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case "UPDATE" :
         return [...state.filter(i => i.id !== action.product.id), action.product]
   }
}

dispatch({type:"UPDATE", product:item})
```

I think this can help you.

Basically you remove the old product item from the array and add the updated one.

Comment: i want to update the quantity, i am not able to update the quantity, i know how  to replace the object from the array please show how to update that object when value is entered in textField....

Comment: you have onchange method on textfield, i guess you can linit that input with just integers, so you call dispatch inside onchange function.

Comment: or use useEffect hook and listen to value of input change and replace the object from the array ...

Comment: i tried but its not working, can u plz do it